# Creating a new contact by using ADB

Tags: android, adb

How can I create new contact using adb?

I'm using the following command:

```
adb shell "am start -a android.intent.action.INSERT -t vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact -e name 'Bo Lawson' -e phone 123456789"
```

But now, Should I need to click  on `Save`, So how can I do it fully automatic using adb?

[image: Contact creation]

Answer (score 0):

You can use adb to simulate touch events by using the following command

`adb shell input tap x y`

Answer (score 0):

Try `adb shell input keyevent 3` This will take your phone back to the home screen which will automatically save the contact.

Comment: it doesn't save the contact when i go to home screen directly